# iOS and SQL xml report

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, xml

I know that there's a lot of posts about that, but i can't find any one that suit my needs.

Here we go: I am developing (newbie dev, of course) an iOS app that is suppose to populate an UITableView with the acquired data from a xml report from a server (mysql and php).
The point is I was able to manually generate the sql report on the server (actually is a wordpress plugin that manually generate and save the report inside a folder on the server) and made the app download it by pointing to the right location of the file (very basic i Know) but is there an easy way of making my app send a request to the server to automatically generate and download the xml?

All the data i must use is inside a database on the server. The parse of the xml is not that difficult and I can handle it. My real problem is allowing the app sending those requests to the server.

Please note that i have no experience in PHP or SQL and have poor knowledgement on that tools so that is what i haven't found any post that suits me as all of them talks in a advanced SQL and PHP language.

All help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to make an NSUrlRequest against a php script on your web server that runs the query and returns the XML as the output. See this link from the Apple guide to get you started:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is too general to give more specific advice than that you should take a look at the Cocoa URL loading system, or alternatively another networking library such [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).